# How do I replace column values in data.frame?

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, apply

I have two data.frame.

```
d <- data.frame(a=letters[1:5], b=c(1:5))
  a b
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3
4 d 4
5 e 5

t <- data.frame(old=c('a','c','d'), new=c('aa','cc','dd'))
  old new
1   a  aa
2   c  cc
3   d  dd
```

And I want to replace like below.

```
  a b
1 aa 1
2 b  2
3 cc 3
4 dd 4
5 e  5
```

I'd like to use apply function.
How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have factors:

```
levels(d$a)[match(t$old, levels(d$a))] <- as.character(t$new)
#   a b
#1 aa 1
#2  b 2
#3 cc 3
#4 dd 4
#5  e 5
```

This will give an error if one of your `t$old` is not in `d$a`.

Comment: Nice option without any packages.

Comment: this does not work if `d=rbind(d,d[3,])` for example .. on the contrary of the other solutions.

Comment: @Roland, ok you are reasonning on the factor, right. My bad I coerced to character and ther was issue with the length of match and the length of t$new

Answer (score 1):

We can use join from  `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d)`) and join with 't' `on' the the first column, assign the 'a' column with the 'new' to replace the values in 'a' from 'd' dataset.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(d)[t, a:= new, on=c('a'='old')][]
d
#    a b
#1: aa 1
#2:  b 2
#3: cc 3
#4: dd 4
#5:  e 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `merge` along with `ifelse`

```
df <- merge(d, t, all.x = T, by.x = "a", by.y = "old")
df$a <- ifelse(is.na(df$new), as.character(df$a), as.character(df$new))
#Removing the "new" column
df <- df[, -3]

#a b
#1 aa 1
#2  b 2
#3 cc 3
#4 dd 4
#5  e 5
```